# Adding Website content to User's Facebook wall

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-timeline

I've seen on some websites where users can select a check box to add specific content to their wall. For example, if they add an image or video to a website, the user has the option to "post to Facebook". Chill.com does this.

Also, SPOTIFY.com add to the user's timeline a notice that says they are listening to a specific tune.

If anyone has any info on this, it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main method for these auto posts are actions

refer to: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/actions/